# Exit status of bash subprocesses

Tags: bash

I've discovered empirically this:

```
# someCommand; echo $?
1
# bash -c someCommand; echo $?
0
```

I expect that `bash -c someCommand` to return the exit status of `someCommand`, instead of always 0.

Is this a bug or a by design feature?
How can I get easily the original exit status?

Comment: That is not the behavior I see: `bash -c 'grep abc 123'; echo $?` returns `grep: 123: No such file or directory` on stderr and `2` on stdout. Which bash version are you using?

Comment: GNU bash, version 4.2.46(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)
That's true.  I don't know how I've tested before.

Comment: My results agree with @Eric's: it *does* return the result of someCommand. For example, `bash -c 'curl http://nonexistent.tld/ &>/dev/null'; echo $?` prints "6" (the status curl returns when it can't resolve the host); `bash -c 'curl / &>/dev/null'; echo $?` prints "3" (the status for a malformed URL). If it's different for you, there must be something about the specific command you're executing that makes it different.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you're getting the exit status of the `bash` command, not of `someCommand`.

`bash` executes `someCommand` and then exits. The exit status of `someCommand` is lost after the bash shell you called exited.

Comment: Thanks for the aclaration, but how to get the exit status?